# Android Studio 3.0 beta2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, build.gradle

When I build my project I got the following error:

> Error:com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/app_debug.kotlin_module'

here is my build.gradle file

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.e9innovation.infrastructure"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../keystores/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = "26.0.1"
    playServicesVersion = "11.2.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.android.support:percent:${supportLibVersion}"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    //apache commons
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'

    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'

    compile project(path: ':searchView')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

P.S. I upgrade my Android studio to 3.0 beat-2 and this issues appears.
Who has idea what is it about?

Comment: For some reason, either Kotlin output of several modules that are packed together in your project contains the same `*.kotlin_module` file, or duplicate Kotlin output is attempted to package (more likely). I will try to reproduce the issue sometime soon. Is your project open source?

Comment: @hotkey no my project is not open source, thank you for the help let me know we can talk in person!

Comment: Also happens in AS 3.0 release.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First Invalidate caches and restart, then clean the project and rebuild it .hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that saved me!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

First Clean the cache by using below command based on your os:

On Windows:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

On Mac or Linux:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

After this clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Add app:build.gradle file

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/app_debug.kotlin_module'
}
```

hope it helps.