# Android Studio 3.0.0 Beta 4 doesn't complain at compile time but fail the build while running assemble for R file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have multiple feature modules in my instant app project structure. All of my resources which are being used in the multiple features are residing in my **core** module.

Assume my **core** module package name is `com.andorid.myapp.core`.

And I have a **feature1** module with package name `com.android.myapp.feature1`.

Now If I am using any resources from **core** module into the **feature1** module, I am referencing it with simply `R.string.something_from_core` and studio doesn't complain anything even I have imported `com.andorid.myapp.feature1.R` not `com.android.myapp.core.R` it just works fine. But when I run `./gradlew assemble`, It doesn't build successfully and throws an error which says the **R.string.something_from_core** doesn't exist.

Now my 100s of my project files are using resources from **core** and I am not able to find which resources are coming from **core** and which are from **feature1** because studio is not complaining anything while writing code it just works. And also the build is only breaking when it tries to run build variants like `assmbleFlavourFeature`, rest everything is working fine.

So confused with no solution, would be great if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a problem with cache.
Try my answer here :
[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845878/android-studio-3-0-beta2/45846639#45846639)

Hope this helps.