# Android SDK 26 build error

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

After I updated to SDK version 26 I tried to build an apk but got this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForFacebookDebug'.
> android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity
```

Stay with SDK version 25 is fine but got error message in build.gradle said:

```
all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
```

Dependency Report (where it failed):

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForFacebookDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForFacebookDebug'.
> android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity
```

Update 1:
I've found the root cause but still, need some suggestions. I looked into dependencies report. Support library 26.1.0 is from another library

```
+--- com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:[10.2.1,11.3.0) -> 11.2.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.2.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.2.2
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.2 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.2.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[10.2.1,11.3.0) -> 11.2.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.2.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.2.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.2.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0,26.2.0) -> 26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0,26.2.0) -> 26.1.0 (*)
\---
```

Update 2:
I've set the facebook sdk usage as below:

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

but still getting the same error

So How can I resolve the conflict from this?

Comment: Add your build.gradle. Some of your dependencies linked to old support libraries

Comment: @DeKaNszn Added

Comment: Can you add output of `./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath` also?

Comment: Try my answer here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845878/android-studio-3-0-beta2/45846639#45846639](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845878/android-studio-3-0-beta2/45846639#45846639)

Comment: @DeKaNszn Check the report I've just added.

Comment: I had this same problem and it's most likely a typo in your build.gradle. Make sure your compileSDK version is 26, build tools is 26.0.1 and all your support library dependencies are 26.0.0.

Comment: @BradenHolt Check the update

Comment: What are your compileSDKVersion and buildToolsVersion set at?

Comment: @BradenHolt 26.0.1 and 26

Comment: Have you tried setting your support library dependencies to 26.0.0 explicitly? Is there a reason why you need 26.1.0? Also I'm not aware of a conflict between sdk26 and Facebook as the user is below, but it may be worth checking to see if 26.1.0 is causing the problem.

Comment: FYI: I'm using appcompat-v7:26.0.0 and facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0

Also: Is there even a v4: 26.2.0 out yet as you have in your dependency?

Comment: @BradenHolt Yea check the change logs on facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x/

Comment: Your version of OneSignal library doesn't understand how dependency version resolution works  in Gradle and unwittingly forces you to use latest Google Play Services package and by extension Android Support library 26. Follow the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949974/android-support-repo-46-0-0-with-android-studio-2-3/42957234#42957234) and adjust for Google Play Services package. Looks like the minimum required version of Google package is 10.2.1.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thanks for inspiring. I've resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I resolved it by assigning version compulsorily. Thanks to @Eugen Pechanec and @ישו אוהב אותך for inspiring me.

```
def gmsVersion = '11.2.2'
compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${gmsVersion}") {
    force = true
}
compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${gmsVersion}") {
    force = true
}

def androidSupportVersion = '25.3.1'
compile("com.android.support:support-v4:${androidSupportVersion}")  {
    force = true
}
compile("com.android.support:customtabs:${androidSupportVersion}")  {
    force = true
}
```

Comment: Congratulations! Now you can mark this answer as asccepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stick with support library `25.3.1`, because facebook sdk version 4.26.0 still using it. You can take a look at its [build.gradle](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/build.gradle), it still using `25.3.1`:

```
// Facebook Dependencies
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
```

For the onesignal error, please read [Troubleshooting Android](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/troubleshooting-android#section-error-all-gms-firesbase-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)n about it, here the excerpt:

> OneSignal automatically adds the following dependencies;
>
> ```
> com.google.android.gms - Version 11.2.+
> com.android.support - Version 26.1.+
> ```
>
> If you get mixed version warnings like above in your build.gradle
>   please make sure to update your other dependencies to match these
>   versions.
>
> If you must keep using an older version of these decencies add the
>   following 4 lines, replacing the versions with the ones you require.
>
> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.+'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.+' 
>
> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.+'
> compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.+'
> ```

Comment: Yea but it will conflict with Facebook SDK since it still using 25.3.1?

Comment: You can try change the sdk to 26.1.0 and use exclude for the support library dependencies in facebook sdk.

Comment: try excluding all the support library for facebook sdk.

Comment: Still getting the error though I remove all dependencies from facebook :(