# Android SDK upgrade from 23 to 26 build error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My application was running fine when using SDK version 23. I tried to upgrade it to SDK version 26 but got build errors. The build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/CHANGES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.futuremobilitylabs.incentrip"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 82
        versionName "0.8.113"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'mediarouter-v7'
        all*.exclude module: 'support-compat'
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    // http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
    // https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout
    //compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The build error I got:

> build failed  8s 664ms    Run build   8s 531ms    Load build  12ms    Configure
>   build 110ms   Calculate task graph    98ms    Run tasks   8s 307ms    The
>   specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.0) is ignored, as it
>   is below the minimum supported version (26.0.2) for Android Gradle
>   Plugin 3.0.1.     Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.    To
>   suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'" from your
>   build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now
>   has a default version of the build tools.     resource
>   style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info (aka
>   com.app.application:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Info) not
>   found.        resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification (aka
>   com.app.application:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification) not
>   found.        resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time (aka
>   com.app.application:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Time) not
>   found.        resource style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title (aka
>   com.app.application:style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title)
>   not found.        failed linking references.
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details       java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details       com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check
>   logs for details

I have read some posts but couldn't fix this issue: [Android SDK 26 build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316151/android-sdk-26-build-error), [Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ (Dependency Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164768/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v727-dependency-error)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241620/errorresource-style-textappearance-compat-notification-info-aka-packageid-te

Comment: _To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools._  Try this which is given in your error log.

Comment: @ZUNJAE I checked the post. However, I didn't use android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification" in the project.  Instead, I used android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium". So I can't fix the issue.

Comment: @VirajPatel Thanks. I can suppress the warning by doing so. Do you have any suggestions to fix the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following line.

```
all*.exclude module: 'support-compat'
```

**Remove it and use the following code to exclude support-v4 library.**

```
all*.exclude module: 'support-v4'
```

or

```
all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
```

You can also exclude support-v4 from specific library as below:

```
compile ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I followed your first suggestion. The original build errors are gone. However, I got other errors as following: error: cannot access TaskStackBuilder
class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder not found. error: cannot access FragmentActivity
class file for android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity not found. error: cannot find symbol class Fragment. error: cannot find symbol class LoaderManager.  I guess that's because 'support-v4' is excluded while I do use a lot of functions from this module. Any suggestions how to address this problem? Thanks

Comment: @LiangTang Remove `configurations {...}` code and exclude support-v4 library from individual libraries like describe above for butterknife library. Using `configurations {...}` is not recommended.